# Redirected CORS request fails on Safari

Tags: browser, cors, axios

I'm sending a CORS AJAX request using the Axios Javascript library, but it seems that Safari is sending an empty request body on the redirect, rather than the actual body (which Chrome and Firefox correctly send).

What's the issue here? Is this a Safari bug? An Axios bug perhaps? Or am I sending the request wrong?

Here's the HTTP stream.

```
POST /session/login HTTP/1.1
Host: api.test.co.uk
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://test.co.uk
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38
Referer: http://test.co.uk/login
DNT: 1
Content-Length: 56

grant_type=password&username=foo&password=bar

HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 18:37:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Type, Origin, Range, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Location: /token

POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.test.co.uk
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: http://test.co.uk
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38
Referer: http://test.co.uk/login
DNT: 1
Accept-Language: en-gb

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.12.1
Date: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 18:37:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 34
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Type, Origin, Range, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1

{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Comment: I follow a lot of CORS issues but the problem described here doesn’t ring any bells for me nor for the author of the Fetch/CORS specs. Also, I’ve not been able to find any Safari/WebKit bug reports related to it, and neither has a fairly experienced WebKit engineer I asked. So in order to isolate the problem, it’d help if you (1) see if you can reproduce it using the fetch API instead — or using XHR instead or even jQuery.ajax() or some other library other than Axios; and (2) see if you can create a test that reproduces it for the same-origin case.

Comment: Specific question: You’re not (somehow) causing the underlying XHR request to be sync instead of async? I’m guessing not, since you’re using Axios, which by design doesn’t allow sync requests. But anyway I’m told there’s a known issue that in Safari a 307 won't be handled properly for sync XHR.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for the response. I'll do some investigation and report back soon.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Okay, so using the fetch API it works all as expected!

Comment: @sideshowbarker But it *does* fail just using plain old XHR. This seems like a Safari bug to me. Could you try reproducing it too, maybe?